# ng-show does not react to $scope.apply

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-show, angularjs-ng-init

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="liveResults">
  <div><img ng-show="home!==undefined" ng-src="{{homeImg}}"> </div>
  <div>0:0</div>
  <div><img ng-show="guest!==undefined" ng-src="{{guestImg}}"> </div>
</div>
```

Inside my controller I fill the data the following way:

```
$scope.init=function() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.example.com/somedata.json", function(result){
      $scope.home=result.home;
      $scope.guest=result.guest;
      $scope.homeImg=$scope.BigImage($scope.home);
      $scope.guestImg=$scope.BigImage($scope.guest);

      $scope.$apply();
      return;
    }
}
```

That function is run by `ng-init="init()"`

now the ng-src is filled correctly, but ng-show does not work as expected (the images are still hidden) I can see using the browsers devtools, that the images are there, but with a width and height of "0".

When I start the function a second time by assigning it to an ng-click-event, the images are shown correctly.

My guess would be that the combination of "ng-init" and "$scope.apply" causes the problem.

Comment: did you try using width and height for the images?

Comment: `ng-show="home"`, infact ng-show is not needed at all, `<img ng-src="{{homeImg}}">` is enough, and you can use $http and avoid $apply call

Comment: @Subin you were correct about ng-show. However. $http does not work for me, here. As I do not want to change the original question, I created a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154809/mimicking-getjson-in-angular. To make it short: It works. Getting rid of "$scope.apply" is another topic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-src` directive already have an implicit `ng-show` in it, so as the comments in you question illustrate this should work for you already:

```
<div class="liveResults">
  <div><img ng-src="{{homeImg}}"> </div>
  <div>0:0</div>
  <div><img ng-src="{{guestImg}}"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-init is needed there as this controller is called from different views with different init-functions

Comment: I followed @Subin s suggestion and removed the ng-show completely. Seemed to work

Comment: (update) tried your suggestion, too for the sake of curiosity. :) Still had the same problem

Comment: I did some more research and @Subin is right,  all you need is to remove the `ng-show`. The answer is now updated