# mimicking getJSON in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I have the following code that **works** in Angular:

```
$scope.yqlProxy=function(url, done) {
  $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
  {
    q:      'select * from json where url="'+url+'"',
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data){
    if (data.query.results) {
        done(data.query.results);
    }
  });
},
```

As the "better" way usually is to use $http I changed the code to this:

```
$scope.yqlProxy=function(url, done) {
  $http.get("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
  {
    params: {
      q: 'select * from json where url="' + url + '"',
      format: "json"
    }
  })
  .success(function(data){
    if (data.query.results) {
      done(data.query.results);
    }
  });
}
```

Now I receive the error "`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is present on the requested resource"

But to get around this error I used the yahoo-proxy in the first place. It allowed me to access an url that does not have that header. With getJSON everything is fine (no error, correct content), but with $http I receive that error. Is there even a way to make this work or do I have to stick with .getJSON (and use $scope.apply to update changes)

Comment: Not sure and I haven't tried, but you might want to set the content type in your GET request (i.e. by setting `headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }`). Maybe that's a reason the yahoo server is answering differently. If not, you might want to check the actual request being sent and check for differences.

Comment: I tried OP's code in jsfiddle, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding the parameter "`callback: JSON_CALLBACK`" what was not necessary in the getJSON-Version.

So the complete request looks like this:

```
  $scope.yqlProxy=function(url, done) {
                $http.jsonp("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
                    {
                        params: {
                            q: 'select * from json where url="' + url + '"',
                            format: "json",
                            callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
                        }
                    })
                    .success(function(data){
                        if (data.query.results) {
                            done(data.query.results);
                        }
                    });
            },
```